# is there any solution to solve instrumented test on android

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-test-lab, instrumented-test

I'm trying to perform `instrumented test` on android studio using test lab, my project is developed using `react native` and imported to android studio, I recorded Test case using `espresso`. the whole process hangs with:

```
Testing started at 1:04 PM ...
"Using Cloud Storage Bucket location test-lab-2tt85ckwy54k0-wuu7mc46q4tqz/as-build_2021-10-12_13:04:11.846_uWyl ..."
Uploading app APK ...
```

I have tried these steps:

- Stopping all running processes
- building an APK of different variants

The testing does not go further than this. please help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the app APK was found and an upload was attempted, but it did not finish successfully as there is no "Uploading test APK ..." message.

As a sanity check, please restart your Android Studio and try again. Also, you might try one of the example projects (e.g., [Topeka](https://github.com/android/topeka)) to rule out any authentication issues.

You might also want to check the Android Studio log for any exceptions that might have happened during the attempted upload as well as double check the size of your app APK, which could impact the upload time.